# Typo3 v8 how to insert current year into copyright from Bootstrap Package?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, dynamic, typo3

I'm looking for a way to set the Text of `page.theme.copyright.text` dynamic to

"© Company Name {year}"

What I have tried:

---

**1.) Marker**:

"© Company Name ###DATE###"

With Typoscript:

```
page.10 {
   marks.DATE= TEXT 
   marks.DATE.data = date : Y
}
```

---

**2.) lib.copyright**

TS:

```
lib.copyright = TEXT
lib.copyright.data = date:U
lib.copyright.strftime = %Y
lib.copyright.wrap= &copy; | 
temp.mainTemplate.subparts.copyright_date < lib.copyright
```

---

**3.) with TS Constant**

TS Constant:

```
page.theme.copyright.text = &copy; Company Name |
```

TS:

```
page.10.variables.themeCopyrightText {
    value >
    data = date:U
    strftime = %Y
    noTrimWrap = |{$page.theme.copyright.text}|
}
```

---

Nothing worked.

What I have:

- Typo3 v8.7.8
- Theme: Bootstrap Package 8.0.3
- no clue how to solve this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a replacement going on ([source](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/8.0.3/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt#L308)).

Use the marker `###CURRENTYEAR###`.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the viewhelper `f:format.date` to show the actual year.
It offers the possibility to format the actual date/year.

```
<f:format.date date="now" format="Y" />
```

for "2017" or

```
<f:format.date date="now" format="y" />
```

for "17".

or using inline notation

```
&copy; Your Company 2005 - {f:format.date(date: 'now', format: 'Y')}
```

which gives you `© Your Company 2005 - 2020`